# Anti-Aliasing in Need For Speed Hot Pursuit

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

How to force Anti-Aliasing in NFS  Hot Pursuit (PC)?

OS: Windows Xp sp3
Graphics Card: nVidia 9800gt

Comment: If the game doesn't have the option, your graphics card software should have a control app where you can specify the default AA level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Need For Speed: Hot Pursuit** does not offer Anti-Aliasing on its own, but you can override AA from within your graphic cards driver software (*Control Panel* for NVidia cards).

This has been working for NFS:HP for NVidia cards since the 266.44 driver.